# jQuery not waiting for the return value of the function

Tags: jquery, forms

I have read many questions like this, but I didn't find suitable solutions. I have two functions one of which returns a boolean. I want to do something when I get the bool result of true. The problem with the following code is,

1. I see this alert first, alert("Please check the name, email and message. Make sure your email address is valid"); ---- (PostComment function)
2. Then I see this alert, alert(data.status); ---- (IsValidEmail function)
3. At the end I see this alert, alert("YES"); ---- (IsValidEmail function)

I want 2 and 3 to execute first, i.e. I want the result from IsValidEmail function in PostComment function before I do something.

```
 function IsValidEmail(emailAddress) {
            response = $.get("https://isitarealemail.com/api/email/validate?email=" +
                emailAddress,
                function responseHandler(data) {
                    alert(data.status);  // 2
                    if (data.status === 'valid') {
                        alert("YES"); //3
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
        }

        function PostComment() {
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();
            var isValid = IsValidEmail(email);
            if (name == '' || email == '' || !isValid || message == '') {
                alert("Please check the name, email and message. Make sure your email address is valid"); //1
                $("#btnPostComment").prop('disabled', false);
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#preloader").hide();
                return;
            }
            $("#btnPostComment").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#Posting").show();
            var url = "/BlogData/PostComment";
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("Name", name);
            formData.append("Email", email);
            formData.append("Comment", message);
            formData.append("BlogId", @Model.Id);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#preloader").show();
                        LoadPartialView(response.blogId);
                        $("#formPostComment")[0].reset();
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                        $("#preloader").hide();
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                        $("#preloader").hide();
                    }
                });
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

The PostComment function, I am calling as follows when the form is submitted.

```
 <form id="formPostComment" method="post" onsubmit="PostComment()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using asynchronous functions ($.get), which continues its execution with callback function, `responseHandler` in your case. And the `returns` in the `responseHandler` have no effect to the parent `IsValidEmail` function, in your case `IsValidEmail` returns `void`. To be able to return a value from function that calls some other asynchronous functions - you need to use `promises`.

```js
function IsValidEmail(emailAddress) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.get(
      "https://isitarealemail.com/api/email/validate?email=" + emailAddress,
      function responseHandler(data) {
        alert(data.status); // 2
        if (data.status === "valid") {
          alert("YES"); //3
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

For you it will be easier to mark `PostComment` function as an `async` function and use `await` in it.

```js
async function PostComment() {
  // ...

  const isValid = await IsValidEmail(email);

  // ...

}
```